# SAN for multiple domain Common name mismatch

Tags: https, multiple-domains

i have 60 domains and bought 2 different certificates, one for www and one for non-www. Since all 60 domains in the SAN there is only 1 domain which matches to Common Name. so i will get this warning from google for 59domains ? Will eveyone who uses SAN for multiple domain get the same warning from Google as follows;

SSL/TLS certificate does not include domain name https://www.example.com/

> Google has detected that the current SSL/TLS certificate used on ...
>   does not include ... domain name. This means that your website is not
>   perceived as secure by some browsers. As a result, many web browsers
>   will block users accessing your site by displaying a security warning
>   message. This is done to protect users’ browsing behavior from being
>   intercepted by a third party, which can happen on sites that are not
>   secure.

Comment: I associate the acronym SAN with storage area network; I'm struggling to imagine how that would have any relevance to your webservers certs. Certainly it has nothing to do with the error you report.

Answer (score 1):

If someone wonders, fixed the issues by putting both www and non www domains into single SAN